# Best way to display listing of items of friends, that are hidden to everyone else, in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a listing of items that are shown to everyone if the item is marked as  status = 1
When items are added, their status could also be 0, which means they are invisible to everyone, unless you are friends with the user who submitted the item. Friendship userid pairs are stored in a different table.

Friends table is 3 columns: friends_inviter, friends_accepter, friends_status   (if friends_status = 1 they are friends). User (their ID) who initiates the friendship is the inviter, user who accepts the friendship is the accepter. So your friends' IDs can appear in either column.

The items table (for this example) has 3 columns also: item_id, item_status, item_owner

What would be the best way to display the **listing** of status = 1 items, as well as status = 0 items, of users who are appearing in your friends list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposition:

```
SET @userID = 1; 

SELECT i.* 
FROM items i 
WHERE i.status = 1
OR  (
        i.status=0 
        AND 
        i.user_id IN ( 
            SELECT f.inviter_id FROM friends f WHERE f.accepter_id = @userID AND f.status = 1
            UNION
            SELECT f.accepter_id FROM friends f WHERE f.inviter_id = @userID AND f.status = 1
        ) 
)
```

[+] I haven't noticed your edit, but this requires your item's table to also have column to distinguish who have added this item

Comment: This seems to work, Im just not exactly sure how well it will scale with a million + rows in each table.

Comment: You may try using `SELECT SQL_CACHE ...` in subselects or moving them to different query and execute it first to get array, than implode this array with comas to get arguments for `IN()`

Answer (score 0):

I made a few assumptions about your tables, like that each item had a foreign key to the user who posted the item.

```
select i.* from friends f
join items i on
    (i.user_id = f.friends_inviter XOR i.user_id = f.friends_accepter)
where f.friends_status = 1
    and i.user_id != $current_user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not give a structure for the items table so this is a guess

```
SELECT * FROM item i 
LEFT JOIN friends f ON f.friends_status = 1 AND f.friends_inviter = i.userid 
WHERE i.status = 1 OR f.friends_status IS NOT NULL`
```